# How to access resource files of an OS X sandbox app written in Golang?

Tags: macos, go, containers, sandbox

I packaged a **Golang** application into a OSX pkg file:

`productbuild --component  foo.app /Applications --sign "test" foo.pkg`

I can install the pkg file successfully, but can NOT launch it.

Because it can NOT read any files in the `/Application/foo.app/Content/Resources`.

I know that the app is running in a sandbox, and it can only read/write `~/Library/Containers/foo` folder.

Basically, there are two ways may let access files int resources folder:

1. Is there any APIs(Golang) available to visite files in `~/Library/Containers/foo`?
2. Can I make `/Application/foo.app/Content/Resources` be installed to `~/Library/Containers/foo`? If so, how to package the app?